# Почему Париж пишется через "ж"?

Tags: произношение, правописание, toponyms

Я бы ожидал либо Парис либо Пари (согласно французскому произношению).

Comment: Потому что заимствовано из польского Paryż. Почему в польском появилось ż — это надо спрашивать на польском StackExchange.

Comment: Не исключено, что в польский язык _Paryż_ попало из итальянского, в котором этот город называется _Parigi_ (парИджи), а может оно и в русский попало из итальянского, это бы объяснило присутствие в слове «Париж» звука И, а не Ы, как в польском. Однако, это лишь мои догадки, в двух этимологических словарях польского языка, которые у меня есть, слово _Paryż_ отсутствует, ни в Википедии, ни в Викисловаре его этимологии тоже нет. Кстати, Ж есть в чешском _Paříž_, в словацком _Paríž_, в венгерском _Párizs_ и в болгарском _Париж_.

Comment: _Предположение_ о польском источнике высказано у Фасмера при разборе слова "парижки". http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?root=config&morpho=0&basename=%5Cdata%5Cie%5Cvasmer&first=9714&encoding=utf-rus

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy - К сожалению, польского StackExchange не существует.

Comment: А по-сербски Париз. Может быть, Париж так назывался ещё в праславянском языке?  Как сами парижане произносили название своего города в V-Х веках?

Comment: @user31264 - «Само слово «Париж» произошло от латинского Civitas Parisiorium — город Паризии. Это было кельтское поселение Лютеция племени паризиев на месте современного острова Сите»: [из Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/История_Парижа#.D0.A2.D0.BE.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B0_.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F).

Comment: @YellowSky - это я тоже прочитал, но вопрос в том, как это слово произносили во Франции и в самом Париже.

Comment: В старофранцузском языке, это слово произносили просто как [pa'ris] если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: Area51 has Slavic languages

Comment: @V.V. It's even not in Alpha. It just collects types of questions that will be good for the site (not for answers). I doubt it will launch in nearest future.

Answer (score 11):

Слово Париж пришло в современный русский через польский, в котором оно звучит (ну, практически) так же  - Paryż. Гипотеза @user31264 не выдерживает критики и проходит по разряду любительской этимологии. И например, у чехов слово Парид - Paříž - ř уж никак не объяснить "потому что так франки на самом деле произносили".

Есть полуапокрифическая гипотеза, что первые карты Франции на территории восточной Европы были отпечатаны в Чехии и в названии столицы была опечатка - и слово читалось как Париш, а потом ш превратилось в ж. Мне не удалось найти каких-то серьёзных научных источников, эту гипотезу подтверждающих.

Честный ответ - я не знаю почему именно "ж", но всё равно не вижу ничего удивительного в том, что Paris читается как  Париж, потому что:

- нередко заимствованное слово не читается по правилам оригинального языка, и немые согласные вдруг читаются.
- произношение продолжает эволюционировать в обоих языка - и из которого заимствовали и в который заимствовали.
- озвончение для славянских языков не редкость.
- переход з в ж не редкость.

Ну вот сложилось так исторически. Там в комментах правильно написали, что возможно это из итальянского аффриката `дж` получилось западнославянское `ж`.

Comment: similar question on Italian SE - http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/7724/why-is-paris-called-parigi-in-italian

Comment: /s/ > /ž/ в старых чешских заимствованиях встречается нередко: *Žofie* — форма имени "София" в святцах, *Ježíš* — Иисус (< *Ježiuš*), *žalm* "псалм", *bažant* "фазан" и т. д. Про причины не знаю.

Answer (score 8):

Согласно **топонимическому словарю** Е.М.Поспелова **"современная французская форма названия - Пари (Paris); принятая в русском языке форма Париж усвоена в искаженном виде через польское посредство"**.

В 58 - 51 гг. до н.э. римские войска Юлия Цезаря покорили Галлию. Попав на пять столетий под власть Рима, Лютеция Паризиорум стали называть поселение римляне.
В 358 году Лютецию переименовали в Цивитас Паризиорум (город паризиев), потом - просто Паризия. Вот так в названии появился звонкий согласный *з*. В 497 году город захватило племя франков, он стал столицей Франкского королевства. Остров Лютеция получил название Сите, а город - Пари. В польском много шипящих, поэтому соглашусь, что переход "з" в "ж" не так уж и необычен, буквы тоже пишутся почти одинаково  (z, ż).

Comment: Так это просто ассимиляция, отражённая на письме, в украинском то же самое: _Париж_, но прилагательное _паризький_

Comment: честно говоря, непонятно, зачем вся цитата на польском если можно было всего лишь указать прилагательное ;)

Comment: Ну то есть это сами франки тоже оглушили согласную, а потом и вовсе выкинули.

Answer (score -3):

Мои предположения:

Как писали YellowSky, Париж кончается на букву ж, кроме восточнославянских языков, в чешском, польском, словацком, болгарском языках, то есть в трёх западнославянских и одном южнославянском.

Париж был столицей Франции с 508 года.  Вероятно, носители праславянского языка как-то его называли.  Судя по сказанному выше, его название оканчивалось на ж.

Как пишeт YellowSky, его название оканчивается на ж в венгерском языке и имеет -дж- в итальянском языке.  По-моему, это всё значит, что сами франки или сами парижане когда-то произносили его название "Париж" (или по крайней мере был такой вариант произношения).

Comment: Интересно, почему же тогда в остальных южнославянских языках это слово будет _Paris_ или _Pariz_, даже в македонском, который многие считают диалектом болгарского, это слово звучит как _Париз_, без Ж, может потому, что географически ближе к Франции?